# Redirect forked process output to NULL

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, embedded-linux

I need to create a function that, among other things, spawns a child process.
I'd like to pass to this function an optional list of file discriptors so that, depending on the user needs, the child process input/output can be redirected.

I have seen dozens of people talking about how to do this using `dup2` somewhat like this:

```
if( pid < 0 )   // error forking.
{
//...
}
else if( pid != 0 ) // Parent process.
{
    ret = waitpid( pid, &status, 0 );
    return  WEXITSTATUS( status );
}
else    // Child process.
{
    dup2( fd, STDIN_FILENO );   // Clone passed file discriptor.
    close( fd );            // Close the passed one, since we have already cloned.
    execvp( arglist[ 0 ], arglist );
}
```

Alright. All of this is in the Internet.
My question now is, how (or what is the best way) to redirect to `/dev/null`?

Should I force the user to `open( /dev/null)` and pass it as `fd` or is there any better way?

---

EDIT:

This is not as pretty as I wanted, but I could not find any better way, so I ended up passing an array of file names to wherever a user could want to redirect, respectively, STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR:

```
static int  do_exec( arglist_t arglist, const char *fio[ 3 ] )
{
DEBUG__( OSU_DEBUG_LEVEL_1, "fio = %p\n", fio );

    if ( fio )
    {
        if ( fio[ STDIN_FILENO ] )
        {
            int fd = open( fio[ STDIN_FILENO ], O_RDONLY );

            if ( -1 < fd )
            {
                dup2( fd, STDIN_FILENO );
                close( fd );
            }
        }

        if ( fio[ STDOUT_FILENO ] )
        {
            int fd = open( fio[ STDOUT_FILENO ], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND );

            if ( -1 < fd )
            {
                dup2( fd, STDOUT_FILENO );
                close( fd );
            }
        }

        if ( fio[ STDERR_FILENO ] )
        {
            int fd = open( fio[ STDERR_FILENO ], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND );

            if ( -1 < fd )
            {
                dup2( fd, STDERR_FILENO );
                close( fd );
            }
        }
    }

    return  execvp( arglist[ 0 ], arglist );
}
```

- I haven't yet fully tested it, so it may have some bugs.

Really thanks to @Zack and @gbulmer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have it as a convention of your API that passing in `-1` for the fd means to use `/dev/null`, and do

```
// ... same as you have ...

else // Child process
{
    if (stdin_fd == -1)
        stdin_fd = open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY);
    if (stdin_fd == -1)
        _exit(127);
    dup2(stdin_fd, STDIN_FILENO);
    close(stdin_fd);

    // similarly for stdout and stderr

    execvp(arglist[0], arglist);
    _exit(127);
}
```

(Psst: Every time you put spaces on the inside of your parentheses, God kills a kitten.)

Comment: I know this will work, but wonder if it is any better way to do that. I could use file names like @gbulmer suggested below, test the strings for NULL and let my API the responsability for opening. This will work too and without restrictions on any file but will still leave me a taste that it must be a better way. Really thanks!

Comment: What would a 'better way' look like to you?

Comment: I'd like to see a solution where I didn't need to explicitly test parameters, open file by name and so on, but I think it will not be possible, so I give up. I'll do what you are suggesting (see my edit). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The child process needs to know which fd's to use as oldfd for dup2 and which fd to dup2 onto.

For example, why would an fd be dup2's onto STDIN_FILENO?

The child needs information for the open fd, and the fd it should be dup2'd onto.

To generalise, to cover cases where files-names, and not just fd's are handled, you will have a way to say "/dev/null" as it is a real file name.

So just have a list of `struct { int oldfd; char* filename; int newfd; }` structs, and the job is regular, and the /dev/null is not a special case. When oldfd is -1 open the filename on newfd instead of dup2'ing onto it.